# What is consuming so much of my system RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory, task-manager, pagefile

I noticed that my system is not going to hibernation state properly since a few days in the past week. I checked a little into my hiberfile size to verify if that was a cause of concern.

The hiberfile is roughly 27 GB in size; which should be good enough, considering that when I hibernate, I generally only have browser and steam windows open.

To dig deeper, I opened task manager; and I notice that it is consuming 24 GB of installed memory.

> [image: task manager]

The consumption looks weird to me, since the process list shows most consumption of memory is by the browser (~2.5 GB)

> [image: process list]

I did a system reboot. On a fresh reboot as well, I see that my memory consumption starts from around 21 GB.

What could be reason for high memory consumption?

---

### EDIT

As mentioned in the comment, I took a look at all the memory related columns in the *Details* pane of task manager:

[image: details]

There are about 24 processes having a peak memory set of at least a 100 MB. Even if I average them to 200 MB, it still is 5 GB.

If I **sum over** the 3 memory columns (active, private and shared), the top 25 most memory consuming processes (sorted in individual category) average to 220 MB each (rounded up). That is still shy of touching the 6 GB mark.

Whereas, the RAM usage at the time of this calculation was 30+ GB.

---

### EDIT 2

Figured out the cause of high RAM usage. [This thread](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/1062131-i-need-to-disable-the-shared-gpu-ram-because-it-eats-my-ram/) seems the closest reason I could find to my issue. Upon inspecting, I notice that my shared system memory is set to half of the total available RAM.

[image: display properties]

Now, I have to search for the specific flag/setting in the BIOS to disable shared system memory for GPU. My motherboard is [STRIX Z370-F](https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-Z370-F-GAMING/). If anyone has pointers on where to look for the said setting in BIOS menu, please help!

Comment: Why don't you look in Task Manager Details tab at the three Memory columns?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Do i sum all 3 column values?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Please check the edit.

Comment: "That is still shy of touching the 6 GB mark." -- Your image shows the top chrome process using 5Gb memory, not what you've calculated.

Comment: @djsmiley2k-CoW where do you see 5gb consumption by chrome?